# Logging large JSON objects to SLF4J incrementally

Tags: java, json, logging, out-of-memory, slf4j

I have some large Jackson `JsonNode` objects in memory. For debugging/tracing purposes, I am logging these using SLF4J-Logback, at appropriate log levels.

This causes OutOfMemory exceptions and crashes, because of the large size of the output string. Note that these `JsonNode` objects are already in memory, so it is not a parsing issue.

Is there any way for Jackson to incrementally "stream" the pretty-printed string to SLF4J instead of generating it all at once?

I'm using code similar to this:

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
...
ObjectWriter prettyPrintWriter = new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
...
if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
    try {
        String dataString = prettyPrintWriter.writeValueAsString(dataNode);
        logger.trace(dataString);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException ignored) { }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact stacktrace?

Comment: Also Log4j `Logger` does not seem to provide streaming operations, and log messages are most likely supposed to be written in one go to guaranetee the whole message is written to the log. What if you write just the very first _n_ characters of the `JsonNode`?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv we use the Logback implementation of SLF4J. And this is just debugging/tracing, data integrity in logs is not a huge concern. You can easily tell if JSON is partially printed.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. You could try to write the first _n_ chars to an n-limited writer (don't know if there are ready-to-use implementations, but it can be easily implemented) that holds a `StringWriter` and log the `StringWriter` result value.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv I do want the full JSON to be logged if possible. It's only in rare cases that streaming may fail.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible at least with your logger since loggers should guarantee that log messages are consistent and written exclusively to the target and not in-middle of concurrently written log messages. You might also write JSON nodes string representation by chunks if it's ok to identify such log messages that are spread over a few log messages somehow. Limited/chunked writing seems to be a better choice than OOM errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you can try using logstash-logback-encoder, create a custom Marker subclass of LogstashMarker and override the method

```
public void writeTo(JsonGenerator generator) throws IOException { 
   ..
}
```

to write your JSON output directly. Perhaps you'll need to write your own appender as well.